# "No value given for one or more required parameters" VB.Net GridView Update

Tags: vb.net, gridview, oledbcommand

I'm having an `Access` DB and connecting to it through `VB.NET`.

First, I show a table records in `GridView` with the user having ability to update it. After the user updates, he will press a `Button` to take the updated data from the `GridView` and update the Access database.

But while doing that I get the error `No value given for one or more required parameters.` What I'm missing here?

**Code:**

```
 Dim sConnectionString As String _
       = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim myAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim myTable As DataTable

Private Sub form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        myConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
        Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID,Test FROM T1", myConnection)
        myConnection.Open()
        myAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand)
        myTable = New DataTable()
        myAdapter.Fill(myTable)
        setDataGridDataSource(myTable)
        setLabelTxt("Row Count: " + myTable.Rows.Count.ToString(), RowCount)
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
        DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE T1 SET ID = ? , Test = ? WHERE ID = ?;", myConnection)
    myAdapter.UpdateCommand = command
    myAdapter.Update(myTable)
    myTable.AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you assign your parameters with values in that OleDbCommand? As it stands right now you don't provide any values to the parameters in the SQL Query.

Comment: @JaggenSWE because I'm using GridView, so the change will happen in the GridView by the user, I don't know how to put the parameters from GridView to the command. Where I will get the updated fields in the code?

Comment: Have a look at this article, it explains the concept quite nicely. It's in c# but the same logic applies to VB.NET and the core of the logic looks more or less identical across languages. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12846/Auto-Saving-DataGridView-Rows-to-a-SQL-Server-Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be edited to this:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Dim cmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myAdapter)
        Dim changes As DataTable = myTable.GetChanges
        If changes IsNot Nothing Then
            myAdapter.Update(myTable)
        End If
        myTable.AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql command with text "UPDATE T1 SET ID = ? , Test = ? WHERE ID = ?;" expects 3 parameters, but your are not setting them anywhere in the code.  [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database) and assign parameters to your command as in:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", txtID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Test", txtTest.Text);
... and so on
```

Comment: @chrisI08 I don't use Input Fields, I'm using GridView, how I can get the updated field from the GridView?

Comment: To get value from gridview cell, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512832/getting-value-from-a-gridview-cell